# Crystal report with linked subreport only working on Report Preview

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I used stored procedure with sql parameters with my main report which is working.

[image]

my stored procedure  for my main report 
[image]

then I tried to add subreport inside the working report with the following stored procedure

[image]

then link Subreport field parameters to my Main

[image]

I checked the Main Report Preview if subreport are working

[image]

Then I run the report but all I see is this
[image]
it just stuck in this message and kept running, I even wait for hours and check if task manager got the report hang, but nope.. It also doesn't have any error message. But in order to close the running report I have to "End Process" in the Task Manager.

so I tried removing the field parameters from the Sub Report as well as links and re-run the report.

[image]

it's working but it's useless to have a report without passing values from main report. because I have date range in it. What seems to be the problem? Why it just stuck on loading of report when I link parameters?

for more info I'm using SAP Crystal Report service pack 16, and IDE as Visual Studio 2015

and this is the code I used for get/set values for parameters on the Main Report

```
 private void SalesByRangeReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;

        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

        TopMost = true;

        DataTable dtSalesByRangeReport = GetData();

        showReport(dtSalesByRangeReport);
    }

    private void showReport(DataTable dtSalesByRangeReport)
    {
        ReportDocument rdoc = new ReportDocument();

        //rdoc.Load(@"Report\SalesByRangeReport.rpt");

        rdoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Report\SalesByRangeReport.rpt");
        rdoc.SetDataSource(dtSalesByRangeReport);

        TextObject txt;
        if (rdoc.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["test"] != null)
        {
            txt = (TextObject)rdoc.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["test"];
            txt.Text = "From :" + StartDate.ToString(" MMMM  dd  yyyy  hh :mm") + " To :" + EndDate.ToString(" MMMM  dd  yyyy  hh :mm");
        }

        SalesByRangeCystalReport.ReportSource = rdoc;
    }


 private DataTable GetData()
    {
        DataTable dtData = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CSPOSWare.Reports.Properties.Settings.fpos_chaplinConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {

            //TODO Mark and Reni : Create a Stored Procedure, Saved in SalesByRangeReport.txt 

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_ReportShowSalesRangeDateTime", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                conn.Open();

                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TopInt", this.TopInt);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SortType", this.SortType);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", this.StartDate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", this.EndDate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeptGroup", this.DeptGroup);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateType", this.DateType);

                //Console.WriteLine("Start Date" + StartDate);

                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                dtData.Load(rdr);
            }

        }


        return dtData;
    }
```

and both of my report have these properties:

```
Build Action: Compile
Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always
Custom Tool: 
Custom Tool Name:
```

So I tried ADDED OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN BOTH ON MY MAIN SP AND SUB SP
MAIN:

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE[dbo].[usp_ReportShowSalesRangeDateTime]
        (                           
            @SortType     Varchar(50),
            @StartDate    DATETIME,
            @EndDate      DATETIME,
            @DeptGroup    Varchar(50),
            @DateType     Varchar(50)
        )
        AS
    BEGIN
        Declare @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(max)
         Declare @ReportCriteria NVARCHAR(max)
         If (LEN(@DeptGroup) > 0) 
            Set @ReportCriteria = ' AND B.Department =  ''' + @DeptGroup + '''';
         If (LEN(@DeptGroup) = 0)
         Set @ReportCriteria = ' ';

            WITH SalesRange AS(
                        Select A.EndDate as [Log Date], A.StoreDate as [Store Date], B.Department as [Department], B.Quantity as [Quantity], 
                        isnull(C.Amount,0) as [Discount], B.AmountDue as [AmountDue],round(B.BasePrice*1.12,4) as [Gross Sales],
                         B.BasePrice + isnull(vsa.Tax,0) as [BasePrice], 
                        case when vsa.type = 0 then isnull(vsa.Amount,0) else 0.0000 end As [VAT Sales Amount],
                        case when vsa.type = 1 then isnull(vsa.Amount,0) else 0.0000 end As [VAT Exempt Sales Amount],
                        B.ServiceCharge as [ServiceCharge], isnull(vsa.Tax,0) As [VAT Sales Tax],
                        case when D.[Type] = 0 Then D.Tax Else 0 End As [Tax],
                        case when T.MediaIndex = 4 then T.Amount else 0 End As [GiftCert],
                        case when T.MediaIndex = 4 then 1 else 0 End As [GCCount]
                        FROM  CSSaleItem B WITH(NOLOCK)
                        LEFT JOIN CSSaleItemDiscount C WITH(NOLOCK) ON B.CSSaleItemID = C.CSSaleItemID
                        LEFT JOIN CSSale A WITH(NOLOCK) ON A.CSSaleID = B.CSSaleID
                        LEFT JOIN CSSaleItemTax D WITH(NOLOCK) ON B.CSSaleItemID = D.CSSaleItemID
                        LEFT JOIN (Select CSSaleItemID, Amount, Tax, [Type] From CSSaleItemTax WITH(NOLOCK) Where [Type] = 0)  As vsa  ON vsa.CSSaleItemID = B.CSSaleItemID
                        LEFT JOIN CSSaleTender T WITH(NOLOCK) ON T.CSSaleID = A.CSSaleID
                        Where   StoreDate   BETWEEN  convert(VARCHAR,@StartDate)   AND  convert(VARCHAR,@EndDate)  and a.RefundStoreDate IS NULL 
                        )
                        SELECT [Department], sum([Quantity]) as [Quantity], SUM([Tax]) as [Tax] , sum([Discount]) as [Discount], 
                        sum(([Gross Sales]+[ServiceCharge])) as [Gross Sales], sum(([BasePrice]+[ServiceCharge]-[Discount])) As [Net Sales],
                        sum(([BasePrice]+[ServiceCharge]-[Discount]))/
                        (Select  sum(NetSales) FROM  CSSale B LEFT JOIN (select csSaleID, Department from CSSaleItem WITH(NOLOCK) group by Department, CSSALEID ) AS A On A.CSSaleID = B. CSSaleID
                          Where   StoreDate   BETWEEN  convert(VARCHAR,@StartDate)   AND  convert(VARCHAR,@EndDate)  and RefundStoreDate IS NULL )*100 as [% Total],
                        sum([GiftCert]) as [Gift Cert Total], sum([ServiceCharge]) as [Service Charge], sum([GCCount]) as [GCCountTotal]
                        From SalesRange
                        Group By [Department] 
                        Order By [Department]  desc 
                    OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@StartDate UNKNOWN, @EndDate UNKNOWN))
                END
```

SUBREPORT:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE[dbo].[usp_ReportShowMedia](
       @StartDate2    DATETIME,
                @EndDate2      DATETIME
                )
 As
        BEGIN


      Select isnull(M.MediaName,'Other') As [Media], 
      COUNT(T.MediaIndex) As [Count], 
      isnull(sum(T.Amount),0) As [Sales Amount], 
      isnull(sum(case when S.EndDate IS NOT NULL and DateRefunded IS NULL Then       S.NetSales Else 0 End),0) As [Total Sales], 
      isnull(sum(case when S.EndDate IS NULL then S.NetSales else 0 end),0) as [Cancelled Sales],
      isnull(sum(case when S.DateRefunded IS NOT NULL then S.NetSales else 0 end),0) as [Refunded Sales]
      FROM  CSSale S WITH(NOLOCK)
      LEFT JOIN (Select CSSaleID, Department from CSSaleItem WITH(NOLOCK) group by CSSaleID,Department) As I ON I.CSSaleID = S.CSSaleID
      LEFT JOIN CSSaleTender T WITH(NOLOCK) On S.CSSaleID = T.CSSaleID
      LEFT JOIN Media M WITH(NOLOCK) ON M.MediaIndex = T.MediaIndex
      Where   StoreDate   BETWEEN  convert(VARCHAR,@StartDate2)   AND        convert(VARCHAR,@EndDate2) 
      group by M.MediaName
      order by M.MediaName
      OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@StartDate2 UNKNOWN, @EndDate2 UNKNOWN))
        END
```

Same Results, I think the from the main report are not passing through the sub report, because it always work only on Preview, but on runtime just stuck on loading.

I Tried sp_who2 Active to check if blocked.
[image]

btw I'm using this connection, on my App.config if this helps..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
</startup>
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <probing privatePath="lib" />
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="CSPOS.Reports.Properties.Settings.chaplinConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=RENZ\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=erika;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
 </configuration>
```

I Checked database permissions on master

[image]

Comment: In which section did you place the sub report inside main report? may be that is causing the problem

Comment: I put it in the Repoot Footer Section of the report

Comment: Why are you converting dates to VARCHAR? "BETWEEN  convert(VARCHAR,@StartDate2)   AND        convert(VARCHAR,@EndDate2) "

Comment: I can remove that but that's not the case here.

Comment: RE VARCHAR: I have tested this and dont't think it will be a problem. Other questions: How many records does the main report return (in your example it is 4)? If you delete all queries from the usp_ReportShowMedia to make it blank or have a dummy `SELECT` like "SELECT 1 as [Media], 2 as [Count], .." does your report work? Try the same with the main report. In summary: just test if blank procedures can be executed when sub-report is configured.

Comment: Alternatively try running your sub-report with non-linked parameters: http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=2241

Comment: Can you run the stored procedure on its own without issue?

Comment: @FatalError Do you have access to run `Sql Server profiler` against the database where the procedures are? If you do, you should start the profiler and then try to run the report. This way you can at least find out if the sub report procedure ever gets called, and if so what the arguments to the procedure are. You have to find the cause of the problem before you can start to fix it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using two sqlcommand instead and eliminate the use of stored procedure.. thanks btw.

Answer (score 1):

I had a situation like this one day. The main issue was in incorrect execution plan for different parameters in stored procedure.

It can be fixed by *OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@param UNKNOWN)*. You can read all about in in [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2008/11/26/optimize-for-unknown-a-little-known-sql-server-2008-feature/).

The second one: there can be some read locks in queries. You can use standard *WITH(NOLOCK)* hint (*READ UNCOMMITTED* isolation level), if report data is not so sensitive.

Try to modify your query to look like this and check the result.

```
SELECT 
...
FROM CSSale S WITH(NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN (... FROM CSSaleItem WITH(NOLOCK) ...)
LEFT JOIN CSSaleTender T WITH(NOLOCK) ...
LEFT JOIN Media M WITH(NOLOCK)
ORDER BY M.MediaName
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@StartDate2 UNKNOWN, @EndDate2 UNKNOWN))
```

You also need to check the stored procedure that you use for main query for same issues.

P.S. Anyway check the *SQL Profiler* for outgoing queries.

Comment: Hi @andrey-nadezhdin I tried the option and WithNoLock Please check if correct (I edited my question and added m pictures to my stored procedure)

Comment: I also wanna know if all of this can be done on unregistered version of SAP CR? (free)

Comment: The query seems OK. But lets try to do it in several steps. Firstly, remove the WITH(NOLOCK) hint and leave only OPTIMIZE FOR statement.

Comment: Can you also write the SQL Server version? I was working on more earlier version on CR.

Comment: Yup I already tried that.. first optimize on main only, then also in subreport, then put no lock on main only, then on subreport as well.. 

Sql Version I'm using is Sql Sever 2008 R2

Comment: You must have SQL Profiler. Try to open it, set that you want to catch such events like: SQL:BatchStarting, SQL:BatchCompleted, RPC:Completed, RPC:Starting. Press "Run", then start yiur report immediately. Look for queries going and update you question with results. If this isn't a test server and there are other queries going, try to filter the result with "Column filter" feature.

Comment: I apologize, I only have SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Advanced SP2

Comment: Nadazhdin I used the Event Profiler.. I'm not sure how to use it but when I generate a report even on the other report that was working it traces "Unable to retrieve SQL text"

Comment: Can you try to add "Max Pool Size=10;" to yours connection string?

Comment: Same result, I'm running out of hope with subreport

Comment: Oh, I forget to mention that you also need to add "Pooling=true;Max Pool Size=10;"

Comment: Can you also post in question your subreport filter settings?

Comment: There can be also an issue with parameters in CR. Firstly -- make sure that filter of your subreport are based on subreport parameters, not linked from the main report. Second, if first step didn't help, create a formula in main report that duplicates the linked parameters and pass them to subreport instead of old ones.

Comment: Nadazhdin yes I put that as well,

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to find if the issue is with stored procedure.

Try to capture parameters passed to stored procedure (`dbo.usp_ReportShowMedia`) of subreport by inserting them into some dummy table (`dbo.subReportParamsTb`) as first statement of SP.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.subReportParamsTb(
StartDate2,
EndDate2
) 
VALUES (
@StartDate2,
@EndDate2
);
```

After running main report, when you are seeing stuck message, check contains of dbo.subReportParamsTb with nolock.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.subReportParamsTb WITH(NOLOCK);
```

If you see parameters are successfully passed to the SP, try to run SP independently with those parameters .

If SP doesn't produce output in limited time, you can try to troubleshoot further by looking at execution plan.

If SP runs fine, you can be sure that issue is not with SP.

Comment: There is SQL Profiler for this /:

Comment: Hi, @Swapnil I tried your test query
`ALTER PROCEDURE[dbo].[usp_ReportShowMedia](
 @StartDate2    DATETIME,
             @EndDate2      DATETIME
             )
 As
  BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.Test(
StartDate2,
EndDate2
) 
VALUES (
@StartDate2,
@EndDate2
);
END`

It still stuck on that loading. and no parameters inserted,

Comment: Hi @FatalError, when report is stuck, execute "sp_who2 active" on the database server to get SPID corresponding to the report. Once you get SPID using sp_who2, use dbcc inputbuffer(spid) to get the sql being executed. I don't know about crystal reports but this exercise will help you understand which sql statement is stuck.

Comment: @Swapnil Hi I tried running sp_who2 active when the CR is stuck on loading, but I don't see any BlkBy, maybe this is why on the task manager it's still running?  I'll edit my question to post a screenshot. thanks

Comment: @FatalError..you may not see block by if it is actually a long running query. Did you try dbcc inputbuffer(spid)? please share screenshots.

Comment: You can try other options: 1) CSSaleItem table is sub report stored procedure is not used. Remove it if you can. If you need it, use it directly "CSSaleItem WITH(NOLOCK) AS I" instead of a sub query using group by operation. 2) If StoreDate is DATETIME remove code to convert input variables to VARCHAR. Use "StoreDate   BETWEEN  StartDate2 AND EndDate2".  3) Run sub report SP from SSMS "EXEC dbo.usp_ReportShowMedia StartDate2,EndDate2;" . Check if it completes in finite time.

Comment: @Swapnil I already have added Screenshots please check the my question,, as for inputbuffer(spid)? what spid would I use? 

As for other option,  that's not the case here..  the query is fine, Like I said the subreport with parameters is working on preview report, I also  Tried executing and it works. no need to alter the query

Comment: @FatalError Looking at sp_who2 results, it seems that no session is running against "erika" database. If you are able to run SP directly using SSMS, there are no SQL code changes needed to fix this.
There is something wrong with CALL to the SP from crystal report. I assume when you PREVIEW the report it is done using your credentials.
Can you confirm that function id used to RUN the report has permissions to i) connect to server/database ii) execute the SP ?
If it has permissions, I am ran out of options too! I hope someone more comfortable with Crystal Report and C# will help.

Comment: how to check @Swapnil

Comment: @FatalError you can use sys.server_principals, sys.database_principals tables to check if user has permission to connect.  To check execute permission refer: https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/44972/how-can-we-find-user-have-execute-right-on-sp-.html

Comment: @Swapnil Hi thanks for the info, I included screenshots atm, is it right? I use master to execute..

Comment: @FatalError You need to run it against database containing usp_ReportShowSalesRangeDateTime and usp_ReportShowMedia SPs. I think there are in "erika" database. If you are not comfortable with this exercise, you can create new dummy report (instead of sub report) using usp_ReportShowMedia SP and check if this report works with credentials of function id.

Answer (score 0):

I think may be it's data linking problem between both of the reports. pls ensure the main report and sub report have unique id and linked properly.